# Duplicate code optimized using a function

Tags: php, function, pagination

I have a bunch of code that I am using for pagination. I use this string of code at the top of a very long page, and I also have the exact same code at the bottom of the page. Duplicating the code doesn't seem very efficient. I am looking to optimize my page by somehow having the code called once at the top of the page, and then have something that just places that same code at the bottom of the page....

I think this can be done with functions, but my php isn't very good and the few tries I've done have resulted in failure. There are alot of variables that go into the function ($total_num_results, $perpage, $p, $pages) and I think that is where I get lost ... Can someone show me how to do this using a function?

Alternatively, I though that I could create an include (and just call the file twice), but I would like to avoid linking to other files...

```
<center>
    Page: &nbsp; <span class="pagination"><?php

    // PREVIOUS link
    if($total_num_results > $perpage && $p!='1')
    {
        $p1 = $p-1;
        echo "<a href=\"mypage/index.php?p=".$p1."\">previous</a>"; 
    } else {
        echo '<span class="paginationon">previous</span>';
    }

    // Pages
    for ($i=0; $i < $pages; $i++)
        {
            $j = $i+1;
            if ($j == $p)
            { 
                echo '<span class="paginationon">'.$j.'</span>'; 
            } else { 
                echo '<a href="mypage/index.php?p='.$j.'">'.$j.'</a>'; 
            }
        }

    // NEXT link
    if($total_num_results > $perpage && $p!=$pages)
        {
            $p2 = $p+1;
            echo '<a href="mypage/index.php?p='.$p2.'">next</a>'; 
        } else {
            echo '<span class="paginationon">next</span>';
        }
    ?></span>
    </center>
```

Comment: `<?php myFunction() ?>` is how you call a function and to create a function - `myFunction(parameters){//code}`. You should create the function before you call it obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          <?php
      function pagination(){
          global $total_num_results, $perpage, $p, $pages; 

          if($total_num_results > $perpage && $p!='1')
            {
                $p1 = $p-1;
                echo "<a href=\"mypage/index.php?p=".$p1."\">previous</a>"; 
            } else {
                echo '<span class="paginationon">previous</span>';
            }

            // Pages
            for ($i=0; $i < $pages; $i++)
                {
                    $j = $i+1;
                    if ($j == $p)
                    { 
                        echo '<span class="paginationon">'.$j.'</span>'; 
                    } else { 
                        echo '<a href="mypage/index.php?p='.$j.'">'.$j.'</a>'; 
                    }
                }

            // NEXT link
            if($total_num_results > $perpage && $p!=$pages)
                {
                    $p2 = $p+1;
                    echo '<a href="mypage/index.php?p='.$p2.'">next</a>'; 
                } else {
                    echo '<span class="paginationon">next</span>';
                }
        }
?>
```

Then in the HTML

```
<center>
    Page: &nbsp; <span class="pagination"><?php pagination(); ?></span>
</center>
```

Comment: I tried this... although, just looking at it, I see some issues. I don't know functions too well, but no variables are being inputed, and no results are being outputted. So, before using the function, my pagination looks like... "Page:   previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 next" (and contains links) .... when I use the function that you suggest, the results are just "Page: previous next" (with no links at all)

Comment: Well if you use global variables they don't need to be inputted as parameters and would be accessible to the function, you didn't post the whole code, where does your $total_num_results come from?

Comment: `global $total_num_results, $perpage, $p, $pages; `
 that is missing from the function itself and be sure to make your variables global! TESTED

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Have some other tweeking to do, but it looks good.